# what is the apache2 domain name and directory root location for Laravel configuration file here?

Tags: php, laravel

I am following the instructions here to install Laravel:  https://websiteforstudents.com/install-laravel-php-framework-on-ubuntu-16-04-17-10-18-04-with-apache2-and-php-7-2-support/

About halfway down it says, "Then copy and paste the content below into the file and save it. Replace the highlighted line with your own domain name and directory root location." Please see below for the highlighted line commented:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>   
  ServerAdmin admin@example.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/MyProject/public
     ServerName example.com //This line here

     <Directory /var/www/html/MyProject/public>
        Options +FollowSymlinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
     </Directory>

     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

So I looked into my `000-default.conf` file and it looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port t$
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

I think my directory root location is `/var/www/html` but I can't figure out what the domain name is (`localhost`?) and also how to input those two things on that one line with the correct format.

Edit:  This is for a local development version?  that I'm trying just for practice in using the framework, PHP and Mysql.

I'm sorry if this is a dumb question but I am a newbie and need to learn this for a new coding job that starts next month here in Sapporo, Japan.

Btw, my interviewer wants me to help him hire more English speaking engineers.  Our stack is PHP with Laravel, Ruby on Rails, Javascript using AWS on the backend, Jira with Confluence and Bitbucket.

It's not official so I can't put up the company name but be forewarned that salaries tend to be lower here.

Comment: Is this for a LIVE site or a development version you are working on locally

Comment: @RiggsFolly sorry I should've made that clear it is for a local version that I'm just trying to get up and running for practice with the framework, PHP and Mysql.

Comment: So that domain name is up to you, but I would suggest that if the LIVE site is called `example.com` then you create a dev version as `example.test` for example. Dont use `.dev` as that is a real tld owned by google

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I'm sorry but I'm more lost now.  Please call me dumb-ass :)

Comment: I left the `laravel.conf` file as it is so when I go launch `www.example.com` in a browser, it goes there and not the Laravel default home screen.

Comment: As (I assume) this is running on your PC, the domain name is anything you want it to be. Its never going to be seen on the internet, only ever on your PC. So the domain name you pick is totally up to you. Once you add your newly invented domain name to your HOSTS file your system will know that the domain `xxx.yyy` can be found on your PC

Comment: @RiggsFolly I think I sort of get what you mean.  I have to create host files as explained here:  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry for such a newbie question but through trial and error I was able to install following instructions at the links below.  Installation instructions for phpmyadmin are included because they are included in the Laravel installation instructions at the site.

Laravel and Phpadmin install instructions

[Laravel instructions](https://www.techomoro.com/how-to-install-and-setup-laravel-5-6-on-ubuntu-17-10/)

phpadmin:

[phpmyadmin instructions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-18-04)